# How can I convert lists into a data set?

Tags: r

I read in an xlsx file that had multiple sheets, so I used this code:

```
hw3.data <- lapply(1:5, function(i) read_excel(file.choose(),
                                               sheet = i))
```

However, I got a bunch of lists, and not the data set as I intended. What should I do in order to view hw3.data as it was in Excel in R?

Comment: I think the code showed would give a `list` of `data.frames`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `[[` to extract the `list` element

```
hw3.data[[1]]
```